# Put views in an Android layout with automatic line break

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to put fixed-dimension buttons centred in a layout so that they automatically go to the next line when they are too many. But I know that this behaviour doesn't work with LinearLayout.

Do you have an idea on how I can proceed?

Here is the behaviour that I would like:

[image]

Comment: I don't see any behaviour on the link.

Comment: The behaviour is that when there are two buttons, a line break is not needed, but when they are 6, then a line break is needed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Flexbox](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) library from Google does exactly this:

Add the dependency to app/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:2.0.1'
}
```

Usage of the layout:

```
<com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
    app:flexWrap="wrap">
        <View/>
        <View/>
        <View/>
        <View/>
</com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

I finally proceeded dynamically : 
I created a LinearLayout for each line, and calculated the width taken by the rectangles compared to the global layout width to calculate the number of lines needed and to put each rectangle in the good line.

Answer (score -3):

This is the [GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) behavior.

Comment: I tried to use it, but without success, because it didn't want to stretch vertically with all its content, but preferred to allow the scrolling. And there was the blue limits on top and bottom when scrolling, so I admit that even if it could stretch to all its content the blue limits would remain. Do you think that it would be possible to customize the GridView to avoid those problems?